# which log file should i use to log spring 4 exception

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I have a Java program which uses both *log4j.xml* and *logback.xml* to log. 
It specifies the paths of logging xml files with:

`java -Dlog.home=D:/xxx -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:D:/temp/logback.xml
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:D:/temp/log4j.xml ...`

It throws  a `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException` and doesn't log to my file. It only displays in my console.

How can I log this `BeanCreationException` to the file appender?

log4j.xml or logback.xml?

Comment: are u using spring boot?

Comment: where u able to try the answer below?

Comment: @PaulJohn thanks, I solved my problem according to [this post](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-log-in-spring-with-slf4j-and-logback/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample log4j.xml setting:

Here is a good tutorial that also covers log4j for spring: http://www.journaldev.com/2433/spring-mvc-tutorial-for-beginners-with-spring-tool-suite

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN"   "log4j.dtd">
 <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- Application Loggers -->
<logger name="com.journaldev.spring">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
<logger name="org.springframework.core">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.beans">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.context">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.web">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
    <priority value="warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

If you are using spring-boot, it's covered in this doc very well: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

Thanks,

Paul